# Terrible performance after SHRINK on static data

Tags: sql-server

In my test environment, on a copy of my 4GB production database, I archived about 20% of my data, then ran a shrink on it from the SSMS, suggesting 20% max free space.

The result was a 2.7GB database with horrid performance. A particular query is about .5s in production, and about 11s now in test. If I remove the full-text portion of the query in test, execution time is about 2 seconds.

Actual execution plan is identical between production and test.

I rebuilt all the indexes and fulltext indexes. Performance is still about the same. No actual content in the test database has changed since duplication.

Any thoughts on where I'd look for the culprit (besides just behind the keyboard? :)

EDIT: ok, repeated the process three times, same results each time... HOWEVER, the performance degrades BEFORE I run the shrink - as soon as I archive inactive records. 0 seconds before the archive, 18 after. Get 7 seconds back after rebuilding some indexes. The archive process:

1. Creates a new "Archive" DB
2. Identifies 3 types of keys to delete, storing them in table variables
3. Performs a select into the "Archive" DB for those three keys from 20 tables
4. Deleted rows from 20 "Live" tables for those three keys.

That's it. Post-archive, when I look at the execution plan 40% time is spent in the very first operation, a clustered index scan.

I'm going to delete this and repost with the question rephrased, over at the SQL site.

relocated question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22337/option-force-order-improves-performance-until-rows-are-deleted

Comment: Strange, only thing I can think of is Parameter sniffing.  You should ask this question on the DBA site.  Probably get higher quality answers there.

Comment: Also it might help if we could see the query with performance problems

Comment: +1 thanks, will try over there. I should keep track of all the various SO sites.

Comment: I wonder how fragmented your tables are now that you've run a shrink.

Comment: @aaron: hmm... seems high only for the table that the main full-text index is on (extent scan 28%, all others are 0%), but I'm not actually projecting any results from that table, only using the full-text index. If I backup and restore will that defragment the tables (as a test)?

Comment: No, backup and restore does nothing with fragmentation, it copies whatever is physically in the source database. You should try rebuilding/reorganizing your indexes (check sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats).

Comment: I did rebuild all indexes. I used http://www.sqldbpros.com/2010/11/sql-server-rebuild-indexes-the-fastest-way/ Any thoughts on that?

Comment: That script seems to rebuild all clustered indexes. Can you post the actual execution plan (not a picture of it somewhere), as I suspect your performance issue is not coming from the clustered index.

Comment: bleh, I just closed out my execution plan and am running a restore, to verify I could replicate the problem. It will be a bit before I can generate another plan. Also, I see what you mean, no wonder my indexes still appear fragmented.

Comment: It's really freaky. I've got the before-defect and after-defect execution plan, and SQL seems to get totally confused about what will perform well after I delete the archived rows. I'm moving this question over to the SQL site.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22337/option-force-order-improves-performance-until-rows-are-deleted

Comment: Solved, over at the proper website for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to delete this in a few days since the question is misleading, but just in case anyone is curious as to the outcome, it was solved here:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22337/option-force-order-improves-performance-until-rows-are-deleted

The shrink wasn't the cause, I only assumed it was because of the likelihood of fragmenting data with a shrink. The real issue was that deleting rows caused a bad statistical sample of the data shape to be taken. That in turn caused the query analyzer to return a bad plan. It thought its plan would scan about 900 rows, but instead it scanned over 52,000,000.

Thanks for all the help!